# How convert ArrayList<int[]> to int[] (primitive array)?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<int[]> al1 = 
   0 = [1,1,1,1,1]
   1 = [0,1,0,1,1]
   2 = [0,0,0,0,0]
...
```

And method must return int[], like this:

```
1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with help of [Guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/31.1-jre):

```
int[] arr = Ints.concat(al1.toArray(new int[][]{}));
```

Answer (score 5):

I would stream the arraylist and apply a flatmap to the `int[]`(s). Like,

```
int[] arr = al1.stream().flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).toArray();
```